# Collecting return types from vararg Callable for use elsewhere in signature?

Tags: python, variadic-functions, type-hinting, return-type

I have the following function signature:

```py
Y = Annotated[TypeVar("Y"), "That which might be yielded"]
R = Annotated[TypeVar("R"), "That which might be returned"]

def teeinto_constantmemory(
         it: Iterable[Y],
         *consumer_callables: Callable[[Iterable[Y]], R]
    ) -> Tuple[R, ...]: ...
```

This function signature is obviously inadequate.

1. It doesn't indicate that the length of the return value is equal to the quantity of `consumer_callables`.
2. Further, it doesn't indicate that the *n*-th element of the return tuple has the same type as **the return type of** the *n*-th element of `consumer_callables` (especially when the callables return different types from each other).

I already checked out [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/), but the closest section they had to relevant was “Type Variable Tuples with `Callable`”, which I couldn't see how to apply to this situation.

Have I missed the solution, or is this use-case actually not yet addressed by Python's type hinting ecosystem?

---

For example, if you call the function with five positional arguments, of types

1. `Iterable`
2. `Callable[[Iterable], int]`
3. `Callable[[Iterable], float]`
4. `Callable[[Iterable], str]`
5. `Callable[[Iterable], FooType]`

then the return value will be of type

- `Tuple[int, float, str, FooType]`

Comment: At the very least, you should define `Y = TypeVar("Y")` and `R = TypeVar("R")` instead of trying to defined them multiple times in-place. `def teeinto_constantmemory(it: Iterable[Y], *args: Callable[[Iterable[Y]], R]) -> tuple[R,...]`.

Comment: @chepner roger that; I'll edit the question to reflect that, to avoid distracting from the core of my question.

Comment: `mypy` also does not support heterogeneous lists.

Comment: I have an answer to this question if `len(consumer_callables)` is known ahead of time at each call site. i.e this function may be called w/ 3 callables in one place and 5 in another, but never with a length which is unknown at type hint time. Is that assumption accurate?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe this _could_ theoretically be solved with `TypeVarTuple`, if/when [higher-kinded type variables](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548) land **and** if they include higher-kinded `TypeVarTuple`s. The latter I have not even seen discussed yet. So I would not hold my breath for this.

Comment: Theoretically I would imagine something like this:
`Callables = TypeVarTuple("Callables", bound=Callable[[Iterable[Y]], R])`
`Rs = TypeVarTuple("Rs")`
`def f(it: Iterable[Y], *callables: *Callables[Y, Rs]) -> tuple[*Rs]: ...`
But at this point this is just my imagination.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment. If each time you tee the input iterable you know how many callables you would like to feed it into, then this works:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable, Callable
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Final

Y = TypeVar("Y")
R1 = TypeVar("R1")
R2 = TypeVar("R2")

class IntoConstantMemory(Generic[Y, R1]):
    def __init__(self, consumer_callable: Callable[[Iterable[Y]], R1]):
        self._consumer_callable: Final = consumer_callable

    def add(self, consumer_callable: Callable[[Iterable[Y]], R2]) -> "IntoConstantMemory[Y, tuple[R1, R2]]":
        return IntoConstantMemory(lambda it: (self._consumer_callable(it), consumer_callable(it)))

    def tee(self, it: Iterable[Y]) -> R1:
        return self._consumer_callable(it)

def calculate_squares_sum(it: Iterable[int]) -> int:
    squares_sum = 0

    for x in it:
        squares_sum += x ** 2

    return squares_sum

def join(it: Iterable[int]) -> str:
    joined = ""

    for x in it:
        joined += str(x)

    return joined

def decrement_each(it: Iterable[int]) -> Iterable[int]:
    for x in it:
        yield x - 1

(output_1, output_2), output_3 = IntoConstantMemory(calculate_squares_sum).add(join).add(decrement_each).tee([1, 2, 3])
reveal_type(output_1)  # `builtins.int`
reveal_type(output_2)  # `builtins.str`
reveal_type(output_3)  # `typing.Iterable[builtins.int]`
```

However, if the number of `add`s is variable length (e.g running it in a loop based on user input or an external file), then Python has no tools to support either your #1 or #2 usecase. That would require a dependent typing system, which no mainstream language supports.

An example of what a dependent typing system would do for you:

```
n = int(input())

into = IntoConstantMemory(calculate_squares_sum)

for i in range(1, n):
    into = into.add(calculate_squares_sum)

res = into.tee([1, 2, 3])
a = res[n - 1]  # No typing error, always guaranteed to work.
b = res[n]      # Typing error, always guaranteed to raise `IndexError`.
```

Comment: \(As a small aside: your code as-written doesn't work in the general case. To tee a potentially unbounded, potentially non-reusable iterable into multiple `for`-loops with constant memory, it is, AFAICT, *required* to either (a) rewrite the consumer functions to use `async for`, (b) rewrite the consumer functions to `yield` during each loop, (c) [synchronize the consumers with `threading`](https://morestina.net/blog/1378/parallel-iteration-in-python#Threads_concurrentfutures), or (d) [synchronize the consumers with `greenlet`](https://gist.github.com/27000568553db5f27bfd29e92bb1072d).\)

Comment: This typing definition *seems* to work, though it requires rewriting the actual interface of the code to be a *lot* more cumbersome, which is a huge negative; the function indeed currently supports arbitrary lists of callables. You're saying that "no mainstream language" has a type hinting framework that allows fully expressing the signature of the function described in the question—what's the most popular language which *does*, if you know of any? (I assume it'd be a Lisp of some kind?)

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I suspected that you were dealing with unbounded non-reusable iterables, but you should change `consumer_callable` to `Callable[[Iterator[Y]], R1]`. A `Callable` expecting `Iterable` generally expects it to be reusable.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I added an edit to my answer. Because you'd like type checking for an arbitrary list of callables, you require a dependently typed language (which can propagate runtime information about input length to output length). Agda, Idris and dependent Haskell are the most popular examples here. If you can talk more about your usecase re. why consumer callables you want to pass are not known until runtime, I may be able to give a better answer.